# Meaning of "thespian pin"

Tags: expressions

What does it mean that a boy gave his girlfriend even his *thespian pin*?

> And they are so in love! He even gave her his **thespian pin** or something.

Answer (score 8):

From my understanding, his *thespian pin* represents a valuable personal belonging here. He gives it to her because he is so in love with her.

A *thespian pin* is a pin you receive once you have done enough hours of shows (theatrical) to be a thespian. For example:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Giving someone your pin is a sign of romantic commitment for young people still in school, who are likely to participate in extracurricular activities that use pins or badges as signs of membership. (Other examples would be a fraternity or honor society pin, a varsity letter, or a high-school or college ring.)